# Можно ли сделать перенаправление с 404 на Главную?

Tags: html

Здравствуйте.
У меня такая ситуация, я загрузил новую версию сайта и поисковик перестал находить старые страницы, выдавая 404. Как мне сделать так, чтобы страница 404 перенаправляла на Главную нового сайта, чтобы не терять поисковые преимущества? Или посоветуйте пожалуйста что-нибудь для моей ситуации. Буду очень признателен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы для этого использовал mod_rewrite, можно указывать redirect 301 со всех страниц, которых больше нет, а можно использовать что-то вроде:

```
ErrorDocument    404    http://www.site.ru
```

Тогда все ошибки 404 будут отображать просто главную Вашего сайта. Но данный подход не очень-то хорош, потому что фактически поисковикам все равно будет возвращаться код 404 (Not Found) от вашего сервера и они будут считать, что данная страница не найдена, поэтому в начале я сказал про redirect 301. Это нужно добавить в файл .htaccess, который должен быть размещен в корневом каталоге сайта. Для того, чтобы использовать redirect 301, нужно прописать примерно следующее:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/old_page.php$ / [R=301,L]
```

Точно не ручаюсь, но что-то вроде этого, далее смотрите документацию по mod_rewrite.

Comment: И чем он не хорош? Самый верный подход, я считаю. Иначе не может быть. Надоиспользовать все ресурсы.

Comment: Так ведь мне и надо, чтобы все удаленные страницы выдавали 404 и яндекс удалял их из поиска, поэтому, думаю, что самый простой ваш вариант он же и самый подходящий, не так ли?

Comment: Ну если так, то да.

Answer (score 0):

создайте файл .htaccess (с точкой, без расширения). в файле пишите:
ErrorDocument 404 'ссылка на файл'
Пример:
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
<p>если сайт на uCoz можно просто добавить файл 404.htm